# Parse DB Design: How to get all the posts for particular category

Tags: mongodb, database-design, parse-platform

I'm creating a discussion system using Parse.com

In my [simplified] system, there are `Post`s, `Category`s, and `Comment`s.

As you probably imagined, `Post`s can belong to one or more `Category`s and can have multiple `Comment`s.

However, often users will want to see all the `Post`s in a `Category`. If I set up my database like this

```
Post (name, content, categories)
Category(name)
```

I am worried that querying for all the `Post`s in a `Category` will be very ineffeficient (since it will have to check the `categories` field of every `Post`.

However, if I design the database like

```
Post (name, content)
Category(name, posts)
```

it will be inefficient for me to query what `Category`s a `Post` belongs to since it will have to search all the `Post`s arrays in the all the `Category`s.

I'm sure this must be a common Database design dilemma but I am still new at this. What is the best way to approach and solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a bi-directional, many-to-many relationship between `Post` and `Category`. With Parse, there are at least three approaches you can take.

1. You can add a column as a `PFRelation` to the `Post` table. You can ask a `Post` for its `categories` relation, create a query from that and run it. Inversely, if you have a `category` you can create a `Post` query with a where clause on the `categories` key. `PFRelation`s are good if you will have big collections.
2. If you think better as a relational model, just create a "join" table called `CategoryPosts`. It would have two pointer columns, one for the `Post` and another for the `Category`. This is also very efficient.
3. Lastly, you could add an array column to either class. Since all of the results are loaded at once, this works best for smaller collections.

These options are described in a little more detail in the [Parse Relations Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations-many-to-many).

Comment: With Option 2, every time a new `Post` or new `Category` is made, I'd have to make an entry in the `CategoryPosts` table? It would get really long soon, especially since `Post`s can have more than 10 categories?

Comment: Correct, these table can get large. That's okay. It's still more efficient than having a column of type array.

Comment: ok that's great to know. I think I will do this then, so I don't have duplicate information and problems later